# Titanium for loop only executes once

Tags: titanium

I'm trying to pass data from an array into a new View object and although the 'accounts.length' returns 6, the loop only get's executed once.

```
var title;
var id;
var button;
var v;
//alert(accounts.length); --> 6
for(i=0; i<accounts.length; i++) {

    title = accounts[i].title;
    id = accounts[i].id;
    button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        backgroundImage: 'images/List.png',
        height:37,
        width: 37,
    });
    menuBtns.push(button);
    v = new HomeView({menuBtn:button, id:id});
    //alert(title'); --> only once
    data.push({ 
        title:title,
        view:v,
        dataType:'dashboardapplication'
    });
}
```

Accounts is a simple multi-dimensional array, HomeView is a layer over a simple View and data is an array that already contains data (same format as for the push statement).
Anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the code you've shown that would prevent the loop from continuing. If I infer the missing variables and functions in your code, I get something like the below, which runs successfully and makes it through the 6 loops. Because of this, there's got to be something wrong elsewhere in your code. Try wrapping your for loop in a `try {} catch (e) { alert(e); }`. Try coming up with a simpler example that reproduces the bug you're seeing. Try removing bits of your code, and seeing what is preventing it from finishing.

```
var accounts = [
        { title: '1', id: '1' },
        { title: '2', id: '2' },
        { title: '3', id: '3' },
        { title: '4', id: '4' },
        { title: '5', id: '5' },
        { title: '6', id: '6' }
    ],
    menuBtns = [],
    data = [];

function HomeView(args) {
}

var title;
var id;
var button;
var v;
alert('accounts length: ' + accounts.length); --> 6
for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    title = accounts[i].title;
    id = accounts[i].id;
    button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title: title,
        height: 37,
        width: 37
    });
    menuBtns.push(button);
    v = new HomeView({menuBtn: button, id: id});
    alert('title: ' + title); // --> 1 through 6
    data.push({
        title: title,
        view: v,
        dataType: 'dashboardapplication'
    });
}

alert('data length: ' + data.length); // --> 6
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, but couldn't fix it yet. I couldn't wrap it in a `try {} catch (e) { alert(e); }` since there are no exceptions to catch. The rest of the code after the for loop is executing fine, but as soon as I do `v = new HomeView({menuBtn:button, id:id});` inside the loop, it breaks.